# How to install KDE along Unity?

Tags: kde

I have just installed the latest Ubuntu 14.04 and I would like to install KDE along side my Gnome/Unity that I have now. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: To get kde you can install the `kubuntu-desktop` package for full kde and other pre installed software on kubuntu.

Comment: If you want the full kubuntu experience as well, you can even install the kubuntu-full package.

Answer (score 37):

You can install kde 4.12 easily on ubuntu 14.04 , open terminal :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

Enjoy using **KDE**

Comment: Just a note, you may need to install software-properties-kde first. I couldn't install kubuntu-desktop until I installed software-properties-kde.

Comment: Just a note: save startkde to .xsession to connect from Windows' remote desktop.

Comment: This no longer works because of this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1424263

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, just `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop` is enough to switch to KDE/Kubuntu.

Answer (score 18):

Good answers here, but when installing you'll be asked a question in a terminal about choosing between lightdm and kdm. Either works well and lightdm should be selected by default, just press [ENTER}.

Reboot/logout, and when you go to login again, you'll see a "gear" icon next to your password window. Click it and select KDE, now enter your password.

This option will be remembered until you decide to change.

Comment: How can you change it back if you selected sddm by mistake?

Comment: This question is old, but I wanted to add that as of October 2016, the KDE developers recommend SDDM over LightDM due to better Wayland support. 

To answer your question: sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm