# Ubuntu to Kubuntu switch!

Tags: kubuntu

I have been running Ubuntu for about a year, now I would like to switch to kubuntu.
Is it possible that I can port all the configuration data from the home folder of Ubuntu to kubuntu? (Without causing some serious trouble)
If I copy all them contents of the home folder (Including the hidden files and folders) will I be able to get the same application configurations ?
I know that copying the Thunderbird folder copies the emails on the newer installation, will it work to other applications?

Comment: The configuration of thunderbird will work on thunderbird and so on.

Comment: @xangua so if I copy config files of inkscape it will work for inkscape? Are there some files which might cause trouble if replaced with the Ubuntu variants

Comment: Do you have to do a fresh installation? You could just install the package `kubuntu-desktop` and have both Unity and KDE desktop environment and tools on one machine. You can chose which one to load at login.

Comment: Will it install all the KDE components that come with kubuntu

Answer (score 10):

If you are upgrading to Kubuntu then no need to copy anything, just install Kubuntu package.

Use one of these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-full
```

[kubuntu-full](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/kubuntu-full) includes [kubuntu-desktop](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/kubuntu-desktop) and also has some additional packages.

You can see how to install Kubuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452083/how-to-install-kde-along-unity) also.

Comment: Will it all the KDE5 apps which come already vith kubuntu 15.04

Comment: Will it come vith the new plasma 5 desktop @PiyushSrivastav

Comment: I just used `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop` to switch Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS to KDE/Kubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

I switched from Ubuntu to Kubuntu. I did a clean install rathere than worrying about trying to save application data etc...

Before performing my clean install, I backed up the following:

SSH keys:

```
tar -czvf ssh.tar.gz ~/.ssh
```

GNU PGP keys:

```
tar -czvf gnupg.tar.gz ~/.gnupg
```

MySQL Workbench Connections:

```
tar -czvf mysqlworkbench.tar.gz ~/.mysql
```

Thunderbird:

```
tar -czvf thunderbird.tar.gz ~/.thunderbird
```

Keyring data (I cannot remember which directory this was in, something like ~/.local/share/keyring).

Sometimes I do the entire backup in one line, but sometimes I find it more convenient to have each backup in its own .tar.gz file.

I then copy the backup(s) to a Samba share and/or USB pen drive, and restore everything after installing Kubuntu (although the keychain/keyring application works differently on Kubuntu, I think).

I much prefer performing clean installs.

Answer (score -3):

You could do it by installing these packages:
kde-baseapps-bin
kde-baseapps-data
kde-icons-crystal
kde-runtime
kde-runtime-data
kde-style-oxygen
kde-window-manager
kde-window-manager-common
kde-workspace-bin
kde-workspace-data
kdebase-bin
kdelibs-bin
kdelibs5-data
kdelibs5-dbg
kdelibs5-plugins
kdepim-runtime
kdepimlibs-kio-plugins

You don't need to copy anything :)
Just choose you wish to run kde after a reboot or log out.

Comment: So I don't need to install the kubuntu package if I install these??

Comment: It is basically the same, but if you want to run kubuntu, install the kubuntu package. You basically get the same result, even though i think that by installing kubuntu you'll get a kubuntu starting image.

Comment: What about installing `kde-full` or `kde-standard` metapackages, and let apt install all required packages for you, instead of installing them manually, one by one?
There's a nice [official guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingKDE) that explains everything.