# How can I make Ubuntu faster?

Tags: performance, gnome-software

I dual boot Windows and Ubuntu.

Nowadays Windows is way faster than Ubuntu (but I still love Linux!)

I checked System Processes and I found that it is GNOME-SOFTWARE using all my resources.
Gnome-software is checking for updates all time.
I hate snaps because they are container based. My cursor theme changes when I hover it into my snap app.
So Do you have any recommendations for making ubuntu faster.(less ram usage?)

> Note:I am new to stackoverflow. This is my first question so please
> forgive me for any misakes.

Comment: You can remove snap altogether https://askubuntu.com/q/1035915/124466 , and install gnome-software with `sudo apt install gnome-software` (instead of snap store). Also consider switching to Xubuntu. It consumes significantly less resources.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Agreed about Gnome.  [Try Kubuntu (KDE instead of Gnome)](https://askubuntu.com/a/613321/327631)

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-full
```

For more background about installing Kubuntu, changing between Gnome and KDE sessions, and removing Kubuntu see [this page of the Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FromUbuntuToKubuntu).

Comment: KDE isn't exactly super light on resources either...