# Big Trouble with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome

I'm not entirely Unix illiterate, but this distribution has got me totally buffaloed.

I can't add the Terminal app to the application loader no matter what I do.  I've now spent an hour researching it, and if I open Terminal, and then right click, there's no option to put it there.

Also, I REALLY don't like Unity, but all attempts to install GNOME have been totally defeated.

Perhaps I'm living too far in the future, but as 2016, somehow I have the impression that installing GNOME should be easy.  I think the terminal app should be easy to add to the left side dock.

But none of this is easy in Ubuntu.  Or perhaps it's just Unity.  I can't tell.

What's going on?   Can anybody tell me why I can't do these things?

Comment: You right-click on the launcher icon and select "Lock to launcher". That's it. Also, installing gnome desktop should work as easy as installing the `gnome` package. What did you try already?

Comment: If you REALLY don't like Unity, you can install Gnome as follows:

`https://askubuntu.com/questions/614657/install-gnome-desktop-ubuntu-15-04`


Or KDE:

`https://askubuntu.com/questions/452083/how-to-install-kde-along-unity`


Or XFCE:

`https://askubuntu.com/questions/223536/how-can-i-install-xfce-along-side-unity`

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal.  An icon for this application will appear in the Launcher.  Right-click this icon (the one that appeared in the Launcher) and select "Lock to Launcher" from the context menu that appears.

For the other issue, please ask a separate question. (One question per post).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to switch to Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS. AFAIK due to an installer bug you'll need to do a clean install if you want to migrate from Ubuntu 14.04.x to 16.04.0 LTS. I did that, got rid of quite some cr*** and now my system's speedy as heck. Also, it sports the old GNOME desktop. Worth a try!

Answer (score 0):

Press [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[t] to open the terminal, right click the icon **on the Launcher** and select "Lock to Launcher".

Other option is search the terminal program, press the Windows Key and write terminal. Keep the windows key pressed to see the keyboard menu.