# Ubuntu 14.04 crashes when watching youtube videos

Tags: 14.04, drivers, intel, crash, youtube

My copy of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS just won't stop crashing when viewing YouTube videos but the worst part is that the problem is inconsistent because I can sometimes go days without any problems and other times I can't watch a single video without the system crashing every time :(. Here are my `lspci` outputs:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 2280 (rev 21)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b1 (rev 21)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 22dc (rev 21)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 22a3 (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b5 (rev 21)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Device 2298 (rev 21)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 2284 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 22c8 (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 229c (rev 21)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 2292 (rev 21)
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b1 (rev 21)
Subsystem: Dell Device 06ac
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

I have an Intel® Celeron(R) CPU N3050 @ 1.60GHz × 2 and an Intel® HD Graphics (Cherryview).

I've got all the latest updates installed for my system and can browse the Net without issue but Youtube is fast becoming a no-go area :(.

UPDATE:

Paste bin link for Xorg.0.log.old: http://paste.ubuntu.com/20292670/

Comment: What does `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` says just after crash? *(it's probably Xorg.0.log.old if graphic restarted)*. But anyway, I'm not sure if anyone has a better suggestion, but I think you'd need to install latest mesa drivers *(e.g. [from a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers))*, and a kernel-4.6 *(there was a rework of intel kernel driver if I correctly remember)*; then, if it won't fix the problem, report a bug.

Comment: I've found the logs but how do I post them?

Comment: Edit your question and add the content of the file. Alternatively, copy the content of the file here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/ Then, add the resulting link to your question.

Comment: I've updated my question with a link to the requested log file :).

Comment: @Terminator I meant the log after the crash, but not just a log. And — you can judge that by time in the braces — if the graphic was restarted, it would be the file *Xorg.0.log.old*, because the *Xorg.0.log* would then be used by the new XServer, i.e. not the crashed one.

Comment: EDIT: I've just found out how to read the .old file and have updated the Pastebin link with the new contents :).

Comment: @Terminator hmm, strange, I didn't see crash errors in the log, looks like XServer just exited. May be it's Unity crashed, and for whatever reason didn't start *(most WMs, e.g. kwin, e20, etc. does restart if crash happened to them, so that session wouldn't lost)*? I'd advice to post `~/.xsession-errors` just after the crash, supposedly, Unity would log problems there. And try a different DE, e.g. KDE, or Enlightement *(err, no, better don't, though it is great, but Ubuntu has an ancient one in the repository)*, or Gnome. And please, use `@` with name in replies, so that people'd be notified.

Comment: @Hi-Angel. What are "DE" and "Unity"? I'm very new to Linux so these phrases mean nothing to me :(.

Comment: @Terminator [Desktop Environment](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/desktop_environment) is a set of graphical apps providing a consistent user experience. Unity.. Well, Unity is both the name of a DE, and also the name of its Window Manager. Don't be misled though: you almost always can use apps from different DEs *(exceptions, probably, some specific configuration apps)*. You can have different DEs on your system, and switch between them from a login manager. [See this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/452083/how-to-install-kde-along-unity) for how to install KDE.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're probably confused also why would I advice installing "a set of utilities" when the supposed problem is a Unity WM. Well, I don't know Unity DE very well, I didn't like it, and I can't advice you to just change WM because not sure what problems with Unity could it cause. So I advised installing another DE to test whether the problem is in Unity, I think it would be the simplest way.